# Missing Positional Arguments Python (Directing to a function)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to figure out how to direct a function to a function. What I'm trying to do is answer a prompt question y/n that would run a certain function. When I input y, it will run through both functions instead of only function 1.

Thanks!

```
def company_type(question, public_company, private_company):
    print("Is the target company public on NYSE or NASDAQ?")
    prompt = f'{question} (y/n)'
    ans = input(prompt)
    if ans == 'y':
        return (public_company)
    if ans == 'n':
        print("Please enter financial infomation manually.")
        return (private_company)
company_type("public_company", "private_company", 1)

# function 1 
def public_company(): 
    return (print("Success 1"))
public_company()

# function 2
def private_company():
   return (print("Success 2"))
private_company()
```

Comment: What do you expect `function(public_company)` to do? You haven't defined `function` and it's not built in to Python. Why not just call `public_company` or `private_company`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a new function as return in python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738031/creating-a-new-function-as-return-in-python-function)

Comment: Or this? [How do I write a function that returns another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261474/how-do-i-write-a-function-that-returns-another-function/14271106)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to return a function.  You just want one function to call another function.  That's done like this:

```
# function 1 
def public_company(): 
    return print("Success 1")

# function 2
def private_company():
    return print("Success 2")

def company_type(question, public_company, private_company):
    print("Is the target company public on NYSE or NASDAQ?")
    prompt = f'{question} (y/n)'
    ans = input(prompt)
    if ans == 'y':
        return public_company()
    else:
        print("Please enter financial information manually.")
        return private_company()

company_type("some question", public_company, private_company)
```

And please note that return statements in Python do not use an extra set of parentheses.  That's a C idiom.

Comment: why are you returning `public_company()` or `private_company()`? those return `print` statements, which evaluate to `None`

Comment: Presumably, those are placeholders, to be filled in with something useful once he gets the mechanics figured out.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! And yes the public and private company are place holders.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely return a function to be used later - this is the essence of functional programming, and the reason to have [**functions as first class objects** in python ~ Guido Van Rossum](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-class-everything.html).

The important thing is to remember that parens mean a function call, whereas no parens mean the function object.

```
def public_company():
    print("we do what public companies do")

def private_company():
   print("we do what private companies do")


def choose_company():
    ans = input("Is the target company public?")
    if ans == 'y':
        return public_company   # no parens
    else:
        return private_company  # no parens


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # assign the returned function to selected_company
    selected_company = choose_company()

    # calling selected_company() will call the selected function
    selected_company()   # use parens, this is a function call!
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Errors:-

- `function` is not a keyword.
- We can call a function by:- `<function_name>()`.

```py
# function 1 
def public_company(): 
    print("Success")
    
# function 2
def private_company():
    print("Success")

def company_type():
    print("Is the target company public on NYSE or NASDAQ?")
    prompt = 'Is your company a public company? (y/n)'
    ans = input(prompt)
    if ans == 'y':
        public_company()
    if ans == 'n':
        print("Please enter financial information manually.")
        private_company()
company_type()
```